# jQuery $(“.class”).click(); - multiple elements, event triggers on all of them

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am working on a TODO app and I am having issues with the event listeners triggering on all of the elements with the same class.

Here is what I have so far:

- "Add New Card" btn on page load, when the user clicks a dynamically generated list gets appended to the page.
- The list is wrapped in `<div>`, containing input and "Add" btn to dynamically add list items to the list.

Roadblock:

- When the user click on the "Add" btn from the dynamically generated list, it adds list items to all lists.

What I've tried:

- I found solutions for triggering the `'click'`  on the "Add" btn only on the `e.target`. This doesn't work in my situation as I am not clicking on the element that needs to be added, I am clicking on the button that should add the content from the input field.
- I tried this inside the function configuring the 'click' but it was unsuccessful.

```
 e.stopPropagation();
 e.stopImmediatePropagation();
```

I have created a codepen here where you can run the existing code: https://codepen.io/skarmen/pen/qBZYZJQ

I would appreciate any guidance and help here.

Thank you!

Comment: Your code does not do anything at all (even after removing preventDefault). Please fix it and make [mre], run-able code with all relevant HTML, CSS and JS. I made a snippet for you as as starting point.

Comment: @skarmen This is a good candidate for `jquery` Event Delegation.

Comment: @ikiK I just created a codepen where the code is running.

Comment: The problem is with `$('ol').append` - `ol` targets all lists on the page. You need to find the list within the same container as the task button and target that one only. You could (for example) find the parent "task-card-container" element of the "add" button, and then .find() the ol within that. Or you could put data-attributes on both elements with an ID which is unique to that card and match those to find the right one. there are a few ways, those are just two common ones. It's not a new problem, the same pattern is observed in many programs, so you can find ways around it.

Comment: You've removed the code from the question and replaced with a codepen.io link - 3rd party only questions are off-topic (not allowed) - the *relevant* code must be in the question.  A 3rd part code link can be included for an extended example, but the relevant code should be in the question.

Answer (score 1):

1 - Save the button `add` you clicked:

```
const add=$(e.target);
```

2 -  pass it into `addTask` function along side input

```
 addTask(userInput, add)
```

3 -  Now use that button to find first list. So inf parent form, then immediately following sibling `ol`

```
$(add).parent().next("ol").append(
```

4 -  You are generating same ids when you generate `taskCardContainer`that wont work, use classes:
`id="to-do-list"` and `id="clear-btn"` needs to be: `class="to-do-list"` and `class="clear-btn"`, ids needs to be unique

```js
$(document).ready(function(event) {

  /* SUBMIT FUNCTION
    - listen to a click event on submit & prevent the default behaviour of the submit event
    - validate the userInput and add it to the list by calling (addTask f)
  */
  function configureSubmitBehaviour() {
    $('.add-new-task-btn').on('click', function(e) {
      e.preventDefault()
       const add=$(e.target);
      const $eventTargetPreviousEl = $(e.target).prev() // e target = btn, so we are looking for the input field before the add task btn
      //console.log('e target:', e.target, 'this:', $(this))

      //console.log('evenTargetPreviousEl:', $eventTargetPreviousEl)


      // store userInput in a variable
      let userInput = $($eventTargetPreviousEl).val().trim()
      //console.log('userInput:', userInput)


      // check if the input is valid
      if (userInput !== '') {
        addTask(userInput, add)
      } else {
        alert('Input cannot be empty. Please enter a valid task.')
      }
    })
  }

  /* ADD NEW CARD FUNCTION */
  function configureAddCardBehaviour() {
    $('#add-new-card-btn').on('click', function(e) {
      e.preventDefault()

      // append the task card container on btn click
      addCard()
      configureSubmitBehaviour()

    })
  }

  function addCard() {
    let $taskCardContainer = $(`
     <div class="task-card-container">
        <h2 class="editable"></h2>
        <!-- Input New Task  -->
        <form>
          <label for="new-task" class="sr-only">New Task</label>
          <input class="new-task" type="text" placeholder="New Task" name="new-task"/>
          <button type="submit" class="btn add-new-task-btn">Add</button>
        </form>


        <!-- Task List -->
        <ol class="to-do-list" class="to-do-list sortable">

          <!-- To do items added dynamically here -->
        </ol>
        <button class="clear-btn" class="btn clear-list-btn">Clear</button>
      </div>
      <!-- Task Board Container ENDS -->
    `)

    $('.main').append($taskCardContainer)
    //console.log('addList works')
  }


  /* ADD TASK FUNCTION
    - add the user input to the list
    - clear the input field
    - function is called upon submit
  */
  function addTask(userInput, add) {

    let removeItem = '<button id="remove">x</button>'


    let checkbox = '<input type="checkbox">'

    // append the added element from the list
    $(add).parent().next("ol").append(`<li>${checkbox} <span data-id="editable-list-item">${userInput}</span> ${removeItem}</li>`);

    $('.new-task').val('')

  }

  configureAddCardBehaviour()
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jeditable.js/2.0.17/jquery.jeditable.min.js'></script>
<!-- jQuery UI -->
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>



<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="main">
    <h2>Goals List</h2>
    <p><em>App description and instructions go here</em></p>
    <button type="submit" id="add-new-card-btn" class="btn">Add New Task Card</button>
  </div>
  <!-- Main Container ENDS -->
</div>
<!-- Wrapper ENDS -->
```

**EDIT:**

Just noticed. You are doing something wrong from start, you have a loop somewhere. All this functions call each other with click events inside them is  messed up.

Now when you have multiple cards, when adding item to list that is not the last one, it will add a list in right place but also loop all next inputs and issue an alert if empty. Pretty sure this is not intentional.